# Malformed \uxxxx encoding error when building Flutter app bundle with keystore.properties

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle, android-keystore

I'm encountering the issue with my Flutter app's when building flutter appbundle  I'm getting a "Malformed \uxxxx encoding" error,

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\flutter new version\new_release\android\app\build.gradle' line: 31
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Malformed \uxxxx encoding.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                           2,883ms
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1

i did flutter upgrade , delete .gradle and gradle files in project root directory.. uninstall flutter sdk and dart sdk and reinstall them and rebuit project, but error still persist,  when runing flutter build appbundle command ,   i am using windows 11

```
this is build.gradle  code that relevent to line 31,    
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))--line 31
}
       Please review and help me resolve this issue. Thank you!
```

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the `key.properties` file. Can you include the content of the `key.properties` file? You can hide the values or passwords

Comment: sure , here it is  ,  storePassword=******
                               keyPassword=*******
                                       keyAlias=upload
                                       storeFile=../app/upload-keystore.jks

Comment: it works changing key.properties like this .... ..    keyAlias=upload
storeFile=..\\app\\upload-keystore.jks
("\\"  insted of '/'....thak you..